# Javscript function running slow

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm collecting a lot of data from an API with an async function that cycles through a lot of data with a loop, I'm making about 100 requests and it takes around 8 seconds.

Are there any methods I can try to use, to speed up my script?

```
async function getplayerdata1() {
  // Get current room
  const response = await fetch(url)
  let teams = await response.json()
  let players = teams.players
  let playerarray = players.length
  for (var i = 0; i < playerarray; i++) {
    // console.log(players[i]);
    let username = players[i].username
    let userid = players[i].id
      // read user matches
    const usermatch = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/user_profile/get_latest_matches?_=&id=${userid}&page=1`)
    let matchlist = await usermatch.json()
    let matchlistarray = matchlist.length
    for (var ii = 0; ii < matchlistarray; ii++) {
      // console.log(matchlist[ii])
      // Read match stats
      const matchlistResponse = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/match/get?_=&id=${matchlist[ii].id}`)
      let matchlistResponsestats = await matchlistResponse.json()
        // get 1st match stats
      async function matchdata() {
        if (matchlistResponsestats.players === null) {
          const kills = 0
          const deaths = 0
          const headshot = 0
          const headshotproc = 0
          return [kills, deaths, headshotproc, headshotproc]
        } else {
          const filterArray = matchlistResponsestats.players[i]
          console.log(filterArray)
          console.log(filterArray.kills)
          console.log(filterArray.deaths)
          console.log(filterArray.headshots)
        }
      }
      matchdata()
    }
  }
}
getplayerdata1()
}
```

Comment: Replace `var i` by `let i` and `var ii` by `let ii`. Look at this for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: It's a good idea to use `let` instead of `var`, yes... but that has nothing to do with the question this poster asked!

Comment: @kshetline Not using `let` causes a bug here in OP's code, since they are using `await` in the iterations, the `i` and `ii` variables will be the last value for all the iterations if they use `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loops with `await` inside, which runs in serial (each request must finish before the next beings), use `Promise.all` instead, with `.map` to map each item in an array to a Promise, which runs in parallel (every request runs as soon as it can, without waiting for other similar requests to finish first):

```
async function getplayerdata1() {
  // Get current room
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const { players } = await response.json();
  return Promise.all(players.map(async (player, playerIndex) => {
    const { username, id } = player;
    // read user matches
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/user_profile/get_latest_matches?_=&id=${id}&page=1`);
    const matchlist = await response.json();
    return Promise.all(matchlist.map(async ({ id }) => {
      // Read match stats
      const matchlistResponse = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/match/get?_=&id=${id}`);
      const matchlistResponsestats = await matchlistResponse.json();
      // get 1st match stats
      if (matchlistResponsestats.players === null) {
        return [0, 0, 0, 0];
      } else {
        const filterArray = matchlistResponsestats.players[playerIndex];
        console.log(filterArray)
        console.log(filterArray.kills)
        console.log(filterArray.deaths)
        console.log(filterArray.headshots)
      }
    }));
  }));
}
```

This will result in all possible requests going out at once. If the API / your connection can handle it, great - but if they can't, you may need to throttle the requests.

Note that in most browsers, only around 6 requests will go at a time; if you make 100 requests at once, only ~6 of them may be active at once. Though, if the underlying protocol is http2, the requests can get multiplexed and sent across in a single go.